Sublime Text - Keyword Normal
When I write a data type like "int", "long long" etc. in sublime text for C++, they get italic, i.e. int, long long. How to keep these keywords straight I mean keeping them normal?
I want a solution to this because when writing longer data types the code become messy.

Use the color scheme customizer to remove the italic style or use the global font options setting to specify that nothing should be italicized.
